# bootstrap grid and columns for 7 fields or more

Tags: bootstrapping

I am using below code for fields more then 7 button fields are scattered

```
<div class="panel-body">
                <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-12 ">
                        <fieldset  class="well well-sm"><legend class="k-widget">main part1</legend><br>


                            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3">
                                <label class="control-label" for="AppEducSclName">Name1: <field here >...... </div>
```

same for next 7 or more fields.

I get my fields in scattered manner means not inline, I want my first four field in first row and then next four in second row and on... but using this code appeares scattered.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: 
I attempted to fix the code from what you provided, and it puts 4 forms in a row, then 4 in the next row, etc (on mobile screens the forms will be stacked to fit the screen)

See my example here: https://jsfiddle.net/vvp5rey8/

Here is the code:

```
<div class="panel-body">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-xs-12 ">

<fieldset  class="well well-sm"><legend class="k-widget">main part1</legend> <br>

<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3">
<label class="control-label" for="AppEducSclName">
Name1: <field here >...... 
</div>

<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3">
<label class="control-label" for="AppEducSclName">
Name2: <field here >...... 
</div>

<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3">
<label class="control-label" for="AppEducSclName">
Name3: <field here >...... 
</div>

<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3">
<label class="control-label" for="AppEducSclName">
Name4: <field here >...... 
</div>

<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3">
<label class="control-label" for="AppEducSclName">
Name5: <field here >...... 
</div>

<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3">
<label class="control-label" for="AppEducSclName">
Name6: <field here >...... 
</div>

<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3">
<label class="control-label" for="AppEducSclName">
Name7: <field here >...... 
</div>

<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3">
<label class="control-label" for="AppEducSclName">
Name8: <field here >...... 
</div>


</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: Yes I wanted to have 7 adjacent fields as well like in 3 column 7 fields

Comment: technically speaking I want three columns three top header and 7 fields under each header